# Upgrade contracts for Corda 4.0 release

Tags: corda

if we want to upgrade contracts for our CorDapp last release, how can be broadcast the latest jar with the upgraded flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the CorDapp distribution service which is part of the business network toolkit. It allows network operators to distribute CorDapps to their participants by utilising Maven repositories for artifact distribution.

It's available as an open source project and you can read more about and download it [here](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/cordapp-updates-distribution)